# Limited Wordpress Menu Items

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, menu, limit

I have an issue with my wordpress site and it's menu items. I seem to have reached the limit, and several posts suggest to increase the php_value max_input_vars, suhosin.post.max_vars and suhosin.request.max_vars in the php.ini file.

It looks like I do not have access to my php.ini file on my webserver, and trying to add this to my .htaccess file causes 500 internal error message.

What are my options in this situation? Do I need to contact my webhost and ask if they can change these values for me? Or is there another way of solving this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can solve the problem using following changes in your php.ini file

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

Read this [Article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-custom-menu-items-limit-in-wordpress/) will also help you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution which works for my host at least:

HostGator Friends – Same Issue & This Solved it:

1. Cpanel > File Manager
2. public_html > wp-admin
3. Click “New File” > name it php.ini (if you don’t have this file already)
4. Click php.ini > click “edit” > click “edit” again
5. Paste: max_input_vars=5000; > Save > DONE

Credit to MINO TAUR on the post: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-custom-menu-items-limit-in-wordpress/